# Regular expression to capture line terminators in a CSV field

Tags: regex, csv

I 've a field "comment" in a csv file who can contains any char and several lines.

Example :

`firstname;lastname;comment
toto;titi;"Hi, you ok ?
yes and you ?"
pierre;tutu;"nice; i love that."
foo;bar;"ko ""lol"""
michu;ferro;"ok ""
but it's strange
"""`

i need to inline each csv records.

Expected :

`firstname;lastname;comment
toto;titi;"Hi, you ok ? yes and you ?"
pierre;tutu;"nice; i love that."
foo;bar;"ko ""lol"""
michu;ferro;"ok ""but it's strange"""`

i tried something like that : https://regex101.com/r/SzJuUl/1 in vain. Someone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Use some regular programming language, read the file in, and run `"(?:[^"]|"")+"` regex and remove linebreaks inside each match.

Comment: Possibly not the best thing to use a regex on. See if your programming language of choice has a library or methods to process a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!")\n
```

It lookout for new line that is not preceded by '"'. Hope it helps.